# Display all the months from M-x calendar

Tags: calendar

M-x calendar would display a three-month calendar and C-u M-x calendar could select the center of the three month.

How could display an arbitrary numbers of months, for instance view all the month in 2019 as bash command:

```
ncal -M 2019
```

Comment: Several years ago, I wrote up a 12-month rotating calendar, with the assistance of multiple threads and help from the Emacs community, including, but not limited to the rotating algorithm.  However, I have not taken any time recently to see whether its compatible with a current version of org-mode.  See:  https://github.com/lawlist/lorg-calendar  For just the 12-month rotating calendar without org-mode integration, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21409154/2112489  For a fancy 12-month, 2-week, 1-week, etc. calendar, have a look at `calfw` library:  https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw

Comment: happy, calfw is amazing,  which provide all I want. @lawlist could please transmit the comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original poster has indicated in a comment underneath the question that the suggestion of looking at the `calfw` library https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw is sufficient to suit his/her needs.  However, that library does not do exactly what the question seeks to answer.  Instead, it has built-in views for 1-month, 2-weeks, 1-week, 1-day.  There is no 12-month view, despite the fact that I erroneously stated it did in my comment.  [Ooops ... sorry.]  Nevertheless, the `calfw` library is very popular and I use it myself.

The closest thing that I am aware of that actually answers the call of the question is a thread from several years ago on stackoverflow ("*Emacs calendar: show more than 3 months?*"):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547912/emacs-calendar-show-more-than-3-months